# How to show 100% for 0 iterations in tqdm?

Tags: python, tqdm

I have a "dynamic total" situation in tqdm, where sometimes the total number of iterations will be 0. And in this case, I would like to show 100% at the end, since all the iterations have been done.

I've tried this:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

bar = tqdm()
bar.total = 0
bar.refresh()
```

but it shows:

```
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
```

rather than something like:

```
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 0/0 [00:00<00:00, 0it/s]
```

How can I get tqdm to treat 0 as a real total number of iterations that has been achieved?

In my case I will have quite a few progress bars, and some of them will have a dynamic total, and so some of them will be discovered to have 0 iterations needed.

I would like to be able to show 100% for the ones that are known to be done, so it's clear what's running and what's remaining.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an iteration that does nothing. So there will be a total of 1 iteration, and the progress bar will show 100%. For example:

```
for x in tqdm(range(1)):
   pass
```

Or as per [@Ake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17973259/ake), if you want a progress bar, with zero iteration, and also a 100% progress to be shown, you can print it out.

```
if bar_total == 0:
    print("100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 0/0 [00:00:00, 0it/s]")
```

Comment: Ah - but the final output will show that 1 iteration? I would like to avoid that since it's a bit misleading in my case

Comment: @MichalCharemza If you have zero iterations, why do you need a 'progress bar' that shows zero iterations? Why not just print out a message that shows 'process completed with zero iterations'?

Comment: If you really want to display that bar you can just use a print statement, I don't think there is a way to display the bar with 0 iterations using tqdm.
`if bar_total == 0:
print("100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 0/0 [00:00:00, 0it/s]")`

Comment: @MushfiratMohaimin For consistency with the case when there aren't zero iterations. Zero in my case is just like any other number of iterations: 1, 10, 100 etc. If it's "done", then I would like to show the same as for the others.

Comment: @MichalCharemza  If you just want to show the same output as others, you can follow Ake's answer, which is literally printing a progress bar. I've added that to my answer.